# noob: uninstall eclipse from 12.04 precise

Tags: eclipse, tar

I'm very new to ubuntu. Today I've installed eclipse kepler, I got it not from the terminal, not from the software center but from their website. It simply downloaded .tar.gz file which I extracted and run a file.

Now I have to change it to indigo version so I'd like to uninstall kepler, what do I need to do?

Comment: can you post the output of running whereis eclipse in the terminal please?

Comment: `me: which eclipse`
`term: eclipse: `
nothing more shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `which eclipse` in the **Terminal**

**If** the result is not found "Empty result"
   **then:** 
just delete the eclipse folder you had created
**else**:
delete the file in the output path, Ex `sudo rm -rf /bin/eclipse` 
**"Make sure from the correct PATH"** and then delete the eclipse folder that you had extracted the tar file in

Comment: Your `else` solution would delete the binary, not uninstall it and it is not clear which folder to delete in this case.

Comment: eclipse doesn't have installer, it just use the JRE to run and it may install a launcher in some path like '/bin/eclipse' which can be found by running `which eclipse`

Comment: Even then you only delete the binary, the other files would remain where they are.

Comment: thanks. The result of `which eclipse` is nothing. It just goes to new line. I deleted folder an had no problems running indigo.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong(fairly new to this, not sure of nuances between builds) but you could try:

`sudo apt-get remove [package_to_be_removed]` #removes associated folders and files

`sudo apt-get purge [package_to_be_removed]` #removes associated folders, files, and config files.

Comment: That would work if the OP had installed the package through the software centre or through apt-get. However, from the looks of things they installed it from a binary package from the website, so apt-get won't know anything about it. (Unless they downloaded a deb package and installed it with `dpkg`...) The OP needs to give us more details before we can answer this. (e.g. what file did they run to install it?) (Actually, it appears that @Ahmed has figured it out.)